# Pure Death Process Question

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I am reviewing for an exam and ran across the following problem. I do not understand pure birth and death processes very well and I was hoping someone could walk me through the following problem and how to solve it? Thank you.

A pure death process starting from X(0) = 3 has death parameters $\mu_0$=0, $\mu_1$=3, $\mu_2$=2, and $\mu_3$=5. Let $W_3$ be the random time that it takes the process to reach state 0.

a.  Write $W_3$ as a sum of sojourn times and thereby deduce that the mean time is $E[W_3]$=$\frac{31}{30}$.
b. Determine the mena of $W_1+W_2+W_3$.
c. What is the variance of $W_3$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: to get from $3$ to $0$ you have to go through $2$ and $1$.  The time you spend in state $j$ is an exponential random variable with rate ...

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it. I was able to verify that $E[W_3] = \frac{31}{30}$. For part b, I got that $E[W_1+W_2+W_3] = \frac{29}{15}$, but I am a little unsure about part c. I think it is $\frac{361}{900}$ I found it by splitting up $Var(W_3)$ into sum of variances of the separate sojourn times. Is this correct?